# How do I load a csv file with complex numbers in julia?

Tags: csv, julia

I am trying to access some complex numbers I wrote to a csv file in julia but I'm having trouble getting it to recognize them. To understand what is happening, consider the following

```
a = [1+2.3im, 2.3+0im]
writecsv("test.csv",a)
b = readcsv("test.csv")
```

Now, if I interrogate the types

```
julia> typeof(b)
Array{Any,2}

julia> typeof(a)
Array{Complex{Float64},1}
```

And I cannot use the elements of `b` as complex numbers, just as a string.(`b[1]` is `"1.0 + 2.3im"`, for instance).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
julia> b = map(x->eval(parse(x)),readcsv("test.csv"))
2x1 Array{Complex{Float64},2}:
 1.0+2.3im
 2.3+0.0im
```

Comment: And since this is evaluating code from the file, you should have extremely high confidence that the file only contains what you expect.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using CSV and DataFrame, you can use

```
CSV.read("test.CSV", DataFrame, types=Complex{Float64})
```